# C++ Shared Library Macro

Tags: c++, qt

I have a C++ shared library. The library has files to be exported. I was using Qt, which makes it quite easy, but I can't use it anymore. So I need a pure C++ variant that covers it for Linux and Windows. So I came up with the following macro definitions.

Pure C++

```
#if defined(_WIN32) || defined(_WIN64) || defined(WIN32) || defined(WIN64)
    //  Microsoft
    #define MY_SHARED_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#elif defined(__linux__) || defined(UNIX) || defined(__unix__) || defined(LINUX)
    //  GCC
    #define MY_SHARED_EXPORT __attribute__((visibility("default")))
#else
//  do nothing and hope for the best?
    #define MY_SHARED_EXPORT
    #pragma WARNING: Unknown dynamic link import/export semantics.
#endif
```

Qt C++

```
#if defined(MY_LIBRARY)
#  define MY_SHARED_EXPORT Q_DECL_EXPORT
#else
#  define MY_SHARED_EXPORT Q_DECL_IMPORT
#endif
```

Currently I'm using the Qt C++ variant.
My question is if it is safe to replace the Qt variant, as seen above, with the pure C++ variant. And are they equivalent?

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: I recommend you to see the definition of the Q_DECLARE_* macro

Answer (score 1):

It's safe to define your own import/export macros. But the one you posted is not equivalent to Qt one because you did not handle the import. It should be:

```
#if defined(_WIN32) || defined(_WIN64) || defined(WIN32) || defined(WIN64)
    //  Microsoft
    #if defined(MY_LIBRARY)
        #define MY_SHARED_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
    #else
        #define MY_SHARED_IMPORT __declspec(dllimport)
    #endif
#elif defined(__linux__) || defined(UNIX) || defined(__unix__) || defined(LINUX)
    //  GCC
    #if defined(MY_LIBRARY)
        #define MY_SHARED_EXPORT __attribute__((visibility("default")))
    #else
        #define MY_SHARED_IMPORT
    #endif
#else
//  do nothing and hope for the best?
    #define MY_SHARED_EXPORT
    #pragma WARNING: Unknown dynamic link import/export semantics.
#endif
```

I'm not 100% sure `__attribute__((visibility("default")))` applies to Linux. In my mind, this was for iOS.

As commented by Rafael, the easiest is probably to simply go to Qt sources (qglobal.h) and copy/paste `Q_DECL_EXPORT`/`Q_DECL_IMPORT` from here to your own header file and then include it from your environment.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I left the imports out because I don't use them. And as I responded to Rafael, the problem with copying the Qt macro's is that they use much more macro's then I really need. Anyway, I will try it and see how it goes. Thanks again!

Comment: I recommend that you copy the Qt macro and then simplify them by removing what you don't need.

Comment: Yea eventually I did that.

Comment: Is there a standard macro which is defined by all compilers when they compiler a library (Like `_USRDLL` in MSVC)?

Comment: @Royi I don't think so.